# How do I bind multiple dropdownlists to a list of enums?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a model with a property "Countries" of type List. Country is an enum. The list can contain 0-5 countries. When I edit this model, I want to use a dropdownlist for each country in the list. I want to be able to select 0-5 countries for the property by using 5 dropdownlists. How do I do this? For properties with a single enum this works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList)
```

The right country gets selected like it should. For my multi-country property this does *not* work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Countries[i], (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList)
}
```

That is, I get my dropdownlists, but the countries doesn't get selected like in the example with the single country.

In my controller I have:

```
ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Country)));
```

Any suggestions? I'm not very good at MVC.

Comment: If you mean that each dropdown is only displaying the first option when you first display the view (rather that selecting the country defined by the model property, then you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the model. This is a known bug with using `DropDownListFor()` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You need to post you model and the GET method (including how you construct the select list for the enum). I suspect you could solve this much easier by using `ListBoxFor()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in MVC5:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
```